# Binding to a relativesource in the code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In my UserControl, I have the following code in my XAML

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=StartTime,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

This simply gets the value of a property from the parent window and it works great.

How can I do this in the code behind?

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor,
                                      typeof(Window), 1);
b.Path = "StartTime";

myProperty = b.value;// obviously there is no b.value but this
                     // is what I'm trying to achieve.

//BindingOperations.SetBinding(StartTime, StartTimeProperty, b);
//This does not work sadly, it can't convert string to DependancyObject
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try [`BindingOperations.SetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx). This should work something like this:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, myProperty, b);
```

(assuming that `this` is a `DependencyObject` and `myProperty` is the DependencyProperty.

Comment: I had tried this, but I didn't' use this I used the property instead.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code which contains the declaration of `myProperty`. In my example, `this` must be a `DependencyObject` (e.g. a `Control`), and `myProperty` must be a `DependencyProperty`. I assume this is not the case. You might have to change `myProperty` to something like `MyClass.MyProperty` (the static `DependencyProperty` field.

Comment: Sorry, my message wasn't meant to say your example is wrong, more that *I* was doing it wrong! Your example is what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Give `x:Name` to your TextBlock -

then you can do that in code behind like this -

```
Binding b = new Binding("StartTime");
b.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor,
                                         typeof(Window), 1);
textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);
```