# programmatic WPF binding fails

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I have a UserControl with a grid in it and I am generating a column of rectangles in my code behind. The UserControl has some dependency properties that I need to bind the rectangles to. I originally did this in the XAML with the following markup:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=MeterBarColor}"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Margin="2,2,2,0" />
```

This binding worked, however I need to build the column of rectangles dynamically so I tried to create a binding in my code behind like this:

```
Dim oBinding As New Binding("{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=MeterBarColor}")
oRectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.FillProperty, oBinding)
```

When I run the application I get errors for each binding attempt saying the property was not found.

Hopefully someone can help me resolve this,
Sid

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19794715/4838058).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of the [Binding constructor you use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597578(v=vs.110).aspx) is a *path*, not a `{Binding ...}` expression. Thus, you need to call `New Binding("MeterBarColor")` and then set the `RelativeSource` property.

Or you could use the parameterless constructor and [object initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx):

```
Dim oBinding As New Binding() {
    .RelativeSource = New RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor,
                                         GetType(UserControl), 1),
    .Path = "MeterBarColor"
}
oRectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.FillProperty, oBinding)
```

Comment: Many thanks, I realized the error of my binding parameter and following your advice my control now binds correctly. I appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: @Sid: You're welcome. You can [mark my answer as the "accepted" answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) using the check mark next to it, so that your question no longer shows up an "unanswered".